# Unique constraint violated - debug

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, sequence

We have an application which is working for years and we are using same oracle database too. But migrated our database from one host to another host.

DB: ORACLE

Now all of the sudden we are getting following exception,

```
“org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (YYY.XXX_LOG_PK) violated; 
SQL [n/a]; constraint [YYY.XXX_LOG_PK]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (YYY.XXX_LOG_PK) violated”
```

code:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TT_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "YYY.XXX_LOG_SEQ")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TT_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Sequence in DB:

```
CREATED 07-NOV-17
LAST_DDL_TIME   07-NOV-17
SEQUENCE_OWNER  TT
SEQUENCE_NAME   YYY.XXX_LOG_SEQ
MIN_VALUE   1
MAX_VALUE   999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT_BY    1
CYCLE_FLAG  N
ORDER_FLAG  N
CACHE_SIZE  0
LAST_NUMBER 75305
```

Problem:
When we are trying to insert some record through JPA code we are getting the above exception but when I try to insert some record into the DB using sequence.nextval, it is not giving any exception.

Is there anyway I can debug to find out what would be the exception ? I also tried show_sql - I couldn't able to find the solution with this too, as this doesn't print the next sequence number in the console

Please point me in right direction, if you know the solution.

Comment: That the error doesn't occur with raw inserts on your Oracle database makes this problem even more insidious.  Is there any chance that Hibernate is creating one or more junction tables behind the scenes, and that this is where the error is actually happening?

Comment: I don't think there is a chance to call hibernate multiple times .... But the right point, I will check it by placing show_sql.

Answer (score 2):

The most common scenario in which a self-augmented sequence encounters a unique constraint conflict is when the data is migrated, causing the maximun value of the data to exceed the sequence value.

> Firstly query the sequanence current values:

```
SELECT seqname.CURRVAL FROM dual
```

> And then modify the sequence value to make sure the sequence's nextval exceeds the current maximum value of the data.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seqname INCREMENT BY XXXXXX;
SELECT seqname.NEXTVAL FROM dual;
```

Comment: CURRVAL only returns the last value of a prior NEXTVAL call in the same session. We would need to check the actual value of ALL_SEQUENCES.LAST_NUMBER .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the problem which we faced.

The problem is from the database end. We found that by reviewing the migration documents and by checking the files.

@Edwin: Thanks for your help, your query also helped me in finding where is the problem residing.

*While doing migration the sequences haven't copied from old server to new server. When we copied to new server, everything worked fine.*

Thanks everyone.